# Nightmare .click event onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to click 'onclick' element. The source of target site is

```html
    <td class="td-03">
        <p class="td-03">hogehoge</p>
    </td>
    <td class="td-04">
        <p class="td-04">
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="this.form.f_comp_no.value=117111;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=431174;" type="submit" value="select1">
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="td-01">
        <p class="td-01">2</p>
    </td>
    <td class="td-02">
        <p class="td-02">162343</p>
    </td>
    <td class="td-03">
        <p class="td-03">foofoo</p>
    </td>
    <td class="td-04">
        <p class="td-04">
            <input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="this.form.f_comp_no.value=11143;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=423271;" type="submit" value="select2">
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to click 'select2'.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
.click('[input[onclick=this.form.f_comp_no.value=11143;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=423271;]')
```

How to click element of `.select2`?

Thanks.

Comment: post the correct and entire html

Comment: It would be much, *much* simpler (and also far better practice) to call a function onlick of the `.select2` element, and then call that function wherever it is required elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Im sorry for mistake.
The same value name.

<input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="this.form.f_comp_no.value=117111;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=431174;" type="submit" value="select1">

<input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="this.form.f_comp_no.value=11143;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=423271;" type="submit" value="select1">

Difference is onclick element...

Comment: Does `.click('input[onclick*="423271"]')` work for you?

Comment: @ArtjomB.Thanks for reply!
I tried it but doesn't work...
Then I tried `.click('input[type=submit]')` doesn't work too...

Comment: @rluisr How do you verify whether the click was successful? How does the page behave normally and what happens when you click? Please show the missing code and ideally an [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

"How to click element of .select2?"

```
$(".btn[value='select2']").click();
```

Comment: Thanks reply.
Im sorry for mistake.
The same value name.

<input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="this.form.f_comp_no.value=117111;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=431174;" type="submit" value="select1">

<input class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="this.form.f_comp_no.value=11143;this.form.f_acnt_no.value=423271;" type="submit" value="select1">

Difference is onclick element...

Comment: @coyotte508 Thanks for reply!
I tried `.click('input[value='select1'][1]')` doesn't work...

Comment: @coyotte508 Thank you reply. I tried `.click("input[type='submit']")[1]` but this is error. I use Nightmare. `.click` method doesn't supoort `[i]`. sorry... please teach me...

Answer (score 1):

One (obvious) thing:

Code can be inside `evaluate()`:

```
nightmare
   .goto(page)
   .evaluate( () => {
       /* Inside browser context, no access to variables from the nodejs
          program unless they are passed as an argument */
       /* using jQuery if it's loaded in the page */
       $(".btn[value='select1']")[1].click();
       /* using native JS api */
       document.querySelectorAll("input[value='select1']")[1].click();
       /* In both cases the [1] refers to the second element matching the css
          selector */

       /* If returning a value here, will be the parameter of the callback
          function of the next .then() */
   }).doStuff....
```

Look at the documentation for [`evaluate()`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2): how to pass arguments to it, how to get back a value from it.

If you want to do the `click()` from `nightmare` itself, it's more complicated, you have to find the precise css selector to find your element directly.

Luckily [this is possible in CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12652010/835629).

So you can do:

```
nightmare
   .goto(page)
   .click(".btn[value='select1']:nth-of-type(2)")
   .doStuff....
```

All this is assuming you have two elements of value `select1` and want to click the second one, if your second element is actually of value `select2` then this would work:

```
nightmare
   .goto(page)
   .click(".btn[value='select2']")
   .doStuff....
```