# How can i get which content reach in second page after page break in snappy pdf?

Tags: html, css, laravel, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I have used snappy pdf for html to pdf. For dynamic page break used

```
.keep-together {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

add keep-together class in every section. That is working fine. Now i need to know which html content reach 2nd page after page break, because i need to apply some style for 2nd page. How can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Add following style and clear your site and the server cache.

```
page-break-before: always
```

Use this style for which you want get element to top of the second page. Also add separate class for that element to identify it is the second page element.

Comment: I can't do that because my element is dynamic. There is no fixed section that will be in second page @kavindalb

Comment: You can add unique class to that element dynamically by calculating how many times print page break class(When it is looping).

Comment: i don't know how to get when the page break execute :( . Your logic is good

Comment: @ShuvroAkash Can you use  :nth-of-type(2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306062/css3-selector-to-find-the-2nd-div-of-the-same-class

Comment: @ kavindalb Thank you so much

Comment: its work for fixed content that display in 2nd page, in my case any component can be in 2nd page. That is why i need to know which components executes after page break