# How to have a sequence of different alternated colors

Tags: html, css

I need that consecutive classes have alternating colors also when interspersed by other (consecutive) classes.

So the green `bb second` in the second picture should have been blue as seen below

need

[image]

now

[image]

```css
.first{
  color: red;
}

.first ~ .second:nth-child(even) {
  color: blue;

}

.first ~ .second:nth-child(odd){
color:green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
```

**Original text**

> It is necessary that consecutive classes are the first first and the next second was an alternating color, and then when back found first again alternated as the picture classes are in order necessary

Comment: The aa first should not be alternating? Only the second? Can you perhaps give the expected color name in the div?

Comment: variables can be used

Comment: sorry, need as on 1 the picture

Comment: So you need it to start over with blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use nth-child with n

```css
.first{
  color: red;
}

.first ~ .second div:nth-child(even){
  color:green;
}

.first ~ .second div:nth-child(odd){
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="second">
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="second">
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="second">
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
  <div>bb second</div>
</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
```

### Adding for comment

```css
.first{
  color: red;
}
.first + .second{
    color:blue;
}
.first + .second + .second{
    color:green;
}
.first + .second + .second + .second{
    color:blue;
}
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:green;
} 
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:blue;
} 
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:green;
} 
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:blue;
} 
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:green;
} 
.first + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second + .second{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
  <div class="second">bb second</div>
<div class="first">aa first</div>
```

Comment: for example there may be different quantities of div

Comment: I don't have a chance to wrap(

Comment: ohh mm and you can use hidden divs with display none?

Comment: Ok, you can use  ++++++ a lot of + to cover all cases if you know some limit...
I will add it to the code. tell me if its ok for you

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to achieve here. But it is not possible with CSS.

`.second:nth-child(even)` selects all the even elements inside the parent and applies the style if it has class `second`. So you cannot select the even or odd elements  of `.second`.

1. However, you can still try `JS` or `jquery`: Run loop over all the elements with the class `second` and apply it to the even and odd elements.
2. You could also use general sibling selector(`~`) multiple times for counting the nth element, although I don't advice it if your data is dynamic.
   Check Ilya Streltsyn's answer here: [:nth-child(even/odd) selector with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458582/nth-childeven-odd-selector-with-class)
   Or: https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/6ka13xve/
3. Enclosing `.second` inside a parent `div` each time you use it

Refer:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

[CSS3 selector to find the 2nd div of the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306062/css3-selector-to-find-the-2nd-div-of-the-same-class)

[nth-child doesn't respond to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428676/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class)

Hope this helps. Cheers!!